# Should I use less local variables or bet on conciseness?

Tags: java, coding-style

I was lately thinking on using local variables for example:

Should I prefer this:

```
String firstString = classString.getFirstString();
String secondString = classString.getSecondString();

ClassGlobal.execute(firstString, secondString);
```

or this;

```
ClassGlobal.execute(classString.getFirstString(), classString.getSecondString());
```

I personally would prefer the later as its more concise and doesn't require two extra instance variables. But is it a good thing to do ? Am I sacrificing code readability for conciseness ? Or is it just ok to use either one ?

Comment: This is to a great extent a question of style. My general approach is to only create a local variable if I am going to use it more than once, or if the construct that I use to assign it is very verbose and would look ugly if used in place of the variable. As far as performance is concerned, I wouldn't be surprised if the compiler doesn't decide to inline many of the assignments anyway.

Comment: I prefer the code to be as simple and clear as possible.  Which do you think is simpler and clearer?  Does naming the variables tell you something you can't work out from the method name?

Comment: (It's the globals there that concern me most.)

Comment: I'll note that the answers have provided almost identical prescriptive advice which could be edited into a single, acceptable-then-close answer...

Comment: second one, because you will have less pointer in stack.

Comment: I'll store it in a local variable if it's worth documenting what that expression is supposed to mean by giving it a name, which is totally subjective.

Answer (score 12):

When in doubt, just remember this quote from [Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/coding-for-violent-psychopaths.html):

> Always code as if the person who ends up maintaining your code is a
>   violent psychopath who knows where you live.

The meaning of this quote is *"make it as easy as possible to understand and read the code."* Later on, if you need to maintain the program again 5 years down the road then it will be easier for yourself if you make it as readable as possible. This is a win-win for everyone.

Comment: upvote for quoting Jeff.

Comment: Wow! this is the most upvotes I've ever gotten on an answer. I never realized the power that a Jeff quote has on credibility and upvotes. Merely mentioning his name attracts people to upvote the post

Comment: It's a particularly resonant quote.

Answer (score 3):

As for me, you should prioritize code readability against minimizing the number of variables. You may perfectly understand that line of code, but for any programmer that retake your code in the future, he'll appreciate the use of local variables (even better if you use good "self-defining" names).

Comment: And everything else ever! Readability always comes first.

Comment: @TFNelson Except when it doesn't, which *does* happen.

Comment: @Dave Newton ah, naturally. All rules are followed without exception except for the exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

In this specific case it doesn't matter much. If your line is readable on its own, there is no need to separate out the variables. However, once you start adding any more logic than a getter, I would tend to split them out. Consider the following code:

```
ClassGlobal.execute(classString.getFirstString().toLowerCase().substring(0, 10),
   classString.getSecondString().toLowerCase().substring(0, 10));
```

This line would be much better if you separate out firstString and secondString and assign them meaningful names. As with most things in code, there's no "best" way. I would tend to err on the side of readability.

Answer (score 2):

I will go for the first one. It increases the readability. For the second one it defeinitely reduces some assign operations (!) but in majority cases this is very negligible amount of performance improvement. So better strict with readability

ALso , you should not care about the premature optimization. Moreover, nowadays compilers do these kind of optimization for you.

Comment: and likely optimized by the compiler in release builds...

Comment: yup .. compilers also does this optimization for you

Answer (score 2):

If you can create more meaningfully-reading code by assigning a good name to the locals, then create the extra locals (also useful if you might need to interactively debug...).

If the locals would not add meaning because the methods being called are that well-named, and you have a pretty ironclad ability to unit test rather than debug and breakpoint.... going for the compact notation can feel better. But more often than not I'd trend toward creation of the locals.

Answer (score 0):

The readability its the most important thing. Try to read your code in 1 year if it's not well readeble and you will get the answer.